# Docker compose exec after docker compose run with service ports

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker compose file which works fine with these commands:

```
docker-compose up
docker-compose exec web /bin/bash
```

The issue I have is that when I want to start the container with --service-ports I can't connect to the container anymore with docker-compose.

```
docker-compose run --service-ports web
docker-compose exec web /bin/bash
ERROR: No container found for web_1
```

I also tried:

```
docker-compose run --service-ports --name container_web --rm web
docker-compose exec web /bin/bash
ERROR: No container found for web_1
# this works
docker exec -it container_web /bin/bash
root@b09618ad2840:/code/app#
```

Any help will be very much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation, `docker-compose run` is used to "Run a one-off command on a service".

For this reason you cannot split your actions in run + exec.

This will work:

```sh
docker-compose run --service-ports web /bin/bash
```

You should use `docker-compose up` to start your services instead of `docker-compose run`.